# json.loads TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

Here is the content of the JSON file

```
{
"error": {
"class": "com.attask.common.AuthenticationException",
"message": "Authentication Exception: Authentication Exception: {0}"
}
}
```

Here is the code where I'm trying to parse the above content. The same code works perfectly fine for parsing other JSON files. But while parsing the above mentioned content I'm getting an error "TypeError: string indices must be integers".

```
import json                                     
fObj = open("attask1.json","r");                
res = fObj.read().encode('utf-8');              
fObj.close();
data = json.loads(res);                         
for each in data['error']:                      
    WFErrorClass = each['class'];
    WFErrorMessage = each['message'];
    print WFErrorMessage;
    print WFErrorClass;
```

Anyone please explain why it is happening and suggest me how to overcome this

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Python version is 2.7.14

Note: Indentation is perfect and no errors with spacing

Comment: Why are you *looping* over `data['error']`? That's a single dict. Just set `each = data['error']`.

Comment: Thanks Aran-Fey, It worked I derived a bad logic to loop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`each` is no longer a dictionary but a string when you run:

```
for each in data['error']:

    print(each) # Returns 'class'
```

Instead all you need is:

```
WFErrorClass = data['error']['class'];
WFErrorMessage = data['error']['message'];
print WFErrorMessage;
print WFErrorClass;
```

Since `error` gets the first part of the dictionary and `message`/`class` gets the second value.

Answer (score 1):

```
for each in data['error']:
```

note that `data['error']` is a dict, so `for each in data['error']` is iterating over a dict, which means `each` is the key of dict, might be "class" or "message", anyway, `each` is a string and can only be indexed by `int`.

your json data should be like:

```
{
"error": [{
"class": "com.attask.common.AuthenticationException",
"message": "Authentication Exception: Authentication Exception: {0}"
}]
}
```